# The name of the IdentityProvider is "(null)" in iOS redirect dialog

Tags: ios, react-native, oauth, single-sign-on, identityserver4

I've created an app using react native and which is using an IdentityServer 4 server to for authentication. I'm using [react-native-app-auth](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth) to perform the authentication.

When I click login the app tries to open the Identity Server login page in Safari and iOS shows a standard dialog to say:
"myApp" Wants to Use "myIdServerUrl" to Sign In.

The problem is, where it should say myIdServerUrl, it actually says (null) as you can see in the screenshot.

[image: iOS login redirect dialog]

Does anyone know why this might be? I'm not sure if its something I've misconfigured on the app side or something I'm not sending back from IdentityServer that I should be. I would have thought it would have just shown the URL that I'm requesting but that's not the case as the login page opens correctly when I click continue, so I haven't provided a null URL or anything.

If anyone knows where iOS looks when populating this dialog that would be a great help.

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT**

After a bit more investigation I've found that a CONNECT request is made to the Identity Server before showing the dialog. This suggests to me that the data it's using is somewhere in the certificate as the CONNECT request is where an SSL connection is requested for HTTPS sites. I'm still not sure what field I'm missing though. I have the Subject Alternative Name populated so I'm not sure what else it could be looking for.

Comment: hi, did you solved this ? might I know how ?

Comment: This was only an issue for us in prelive. Once we deployed to live the correct domain was shown. Are you having this problem in live?

Comment: you mean you deploed ios app on live or backend identityServer on live ? or what do you mean by live ? we have some public domain under which our identityServer works, but we also check burb logs and seems ios app does not send any request to identityServer before showing this null screen

Answer (score 0):

## EDIT

It seems, if the URL has a recognizable [top-level domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains), the domain name (as defined [here](https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/seo-glossary-url-definitions/)) will be reported by the dialog. For example, `some.host.name.zw` will be referred as `name.zw` and `video.google.co.uk` as `google.co.uk`.

Otherwise, `("null")` is produced, as in case of `some.host.name.local`, etc.

It is still an empirical finding, I don't have any official reference to this, but one that is easy to test.

Comment: could you elaborate on that ?

Comment: The above was found empirically, but this seems to confirm my findings: https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth/issues/135. To recup: 1) if there is no SSL certificate, as in the case of `sqlfiddle.com` or `customers.mapoptix.com` (at least for now) or an HTTP URL is used and there is no auto-redirection to HTTPS - the dialog produced by Swift authentication classes still shows the domain name; hence, this info does not seem to come from the certificate; 2) subdomains are not shown; `guides.libraries.psu.edu` becomes `psu.edu`, `video.google.co.uk` becomes `google.co.uk`, etc.

Comment: with burb we found that before ios app shows this screen with null, there is no any request send to backend with identity server, so this looks like internal ios app configuration.

Comment: See the updated answer. The remaining parts are: 1) has nothing to do with TLS certificate, 2) the domain is reported (with the condition that its top-level part is recognized).